# How can I get rgb value from point cloud

Tags: c++, rgb, point-cloud-library

I have a point-cloud. I want to get its RGB value. How can I do that?
  To make my question clearer, please see the codes.

```
// Load the first input file into a PointCloud<T> with an appropriate type : 
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud1 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
        if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ("../data/station1.pcd", *cloud1) == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Error reading PCD file !!!" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
```

I want to get each value alone

```
std::cout << " x = " << cloud1->points[11].x << std::endl;
std::cout << " y = " << cloud1->points[11].y << std::endl;
std::cout << " z = " << cloud1->points[11].z << std::endl;
std::cout << " r = " << cloud1->points[11].r << std::endl;
std::cout << " g = " << cloud1->points[11].g << std::endl;
std::cout << " b = " << cloud1->points[11].b << std::endl;
```

But as a result I get something like that :

```
 x = 2.33672
 y = 3.8102
 z = 8.86153
 r = �
 g = w
 b = �
```

Answer (score 5):

[From the point cloud docs](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html):

A point structure representing Euclidean xyz coordinates, and the [RGB](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_r_g_b.html) color.

Due to historical reasons (PCL was first developed as a ROS package), the [RGB](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_r_g_b.html) information is packed into an integer and casted to a float. This is something we wish to remove in the near future, but in the meantime, the following code snippet should help you pack and unpack [RGB](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_r_g_b.html) colors in your [PointXYZRGB](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html) structure:

```
// pack r/g/b into rgb
uint8_t r = 255, g = 0, b = 0;    // Example: Red color
uint32_t rgb = ((uint32_t)r << 16 | (uint32_t)g << 8 | (uint32_t)b);
p.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
```

To unpack the data into separate values, use:

```
PointXYZRGB p;
// unpack rgb into r/g/b
uint32_t rgb = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&p.rgb);
uint8_t r = (rgb >> 16) & 0x0000ff;
uint8_t g = (rgb >> 8)  & 0x0000ff;
uint8_t b = (rgb)       & 0x0000ff;
```

Alternatively, from 1.1.0 onwards, you can use p.r, p.g, and p.b directly.

Definition at line [559](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/point__types_8hpp_source.html#l00559) of file [point_types.hpp](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/point__types_8hpp_source.html).

Comment: thank you @Kevin; But I still get the same error; this is the new code :  
  ` uint32_t rgb = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&cloud1->points[11].rgb);
    uint8_t r = (rgb >> 16) & 0x0000ff;
    uint8_t g = (rgb >> 8)  & 0x0000ff;
    uint8_t b = (rgb)       & 0x0000ff;
    std::cout << " x = " << cloud1->points[11].x << std::endl;
    std::cout << " y = " << cloud1->points[11].y << std::endl;
    std::cout << " z = " << cloud1->points[11].z << std::endl;
    std::cout << " r = " << r << std::endl;
    std::cout << " g = " << g << std::endl;
    std::cout << " b = " << b << std::endl; `

Comment: I succeed to solve it! actually the R, G and B values are of type unsigned char, thus we need to cast them to int to see their numeric values.
I try: `std::cout << " r = " << int(cloud1->points[11].r) << std::endl;` and it works

Comment: Make that (int)cloud1->points[11].r though ;) You are now calling the constructor of int (creating a new variable and returning it to output with cout), not casting the value to int type.